# Ввод текста с клавиатуры в массив

Tags: массивы, c++

Сделала суть задания. Не получается вводить именно текст с 12 строками.

Задание: ввести текст с клавиатуры, число строк которого строго 12, а также массив разделителей. В строках, в которых встречается указанное слово, заменить это слово на другое, также введённое пользователем. Вот, что вышло у меня:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char * tmp;
    char stroka[200];
    char mas[12][12];
    char slovo[20];
    char zamena[20];
    int i, word_count = 0;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    gets_s(stroka);
    printf("Enter word to change:");
    gets_s(slovo);
    printf("Enter word for change:");
    gets_s(zamena);

    tmp = strtok(stroka, " ,");
    for (i = 0; tmp != '\0'; i++) {
        strcpy(mas[i], tmp);
        tmp = strtok(NULL, " ,");
        word_count++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(mas[i], slovo) == NULL)
            strcpy(mas[i], zamena);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < word_count; i++)
        printf("%s ", mas[i]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пара подсказок:  

> Ввести текст с клавиатуры, число строк которого строго 12

Следовательно, двенадцать раз надо выполнить операцию чтения - что практически автоматом означает цикл и массив из двенадцати элементов-строк.

    char mas[12][12];

Получится 12 строк по 12 символов. Нужно задавать либо 12 строк по `ДЛИНА_СТРОКИ_МАКС`

    char text[12][200]

Либо не ограничивать длину строк на этом этапе вообще

    char text[12][]

Comment: @himiko, обычно в программе длеают константу типа `const int MAX_LENGTH = 200;`, которую потом используют для инициализации строк. У вас, очевидно, таким значением в данный момент является 200. Инициализация, понятное дело, будет выглядеть так:

    char line[MAX_LENGTH];

Comment: @himiko, лучше сразу почитайте про указатели (и посмотрите `man strdup`).

Тогда все упростится. Делаете массив из 12 указателей

     char *a12[12];

В цикле 12 раз читаете по одной строке и запоминаете в массиве адреса их копий

     for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        char s[LINE_MAX];
        if (!fgets(s, LINE_MAX, stdin)) {
           printf ("Unexpected EOF\n"); exit(1);
        }
        s[strlen(s) - 1] = 0; // уберем \n в конце строки
        a12[i] = strdup(s);
     }

Вот в таком духе и начинайте.

Comment: Должен немного уточнить. При вводе с клавиатуры это практически не актуально, но в принципе возможен случай, когда последняя строка в файле будет *без `\n` в конце*.

Поэтому более правильно (безопасно, но чуть медленнее, чем `strlen`) удалять `\n` в конце строки так:

      s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = 0;

(см. `man strcspn`)